# can't find the crash reason from ios crash report

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

[image]

As you can see, it crashes by calling `() -> ()` (void and no return) type function.

I don't understand what's happening.

Does the `+ 3412` tell me something valuable?

Does the stack show wrong info because my current code is not the same as when I submitted the app to the appstore?

** edit **

@Avijit Nagare

I'm viewing crash reports downloaded from apple for my published app. maybe that's why those `show report navigator` is unselectable?

[image]

@Atrash

maybeSendRegistration is not nil.

```
func maybeSendRegistration() {

    let user = GlobalStorage.sharedInstance.getUser()

    if user.isAuthenticated() == false {
        return
    }

   .. omitted
```

Comment: Could you try "Show report navigator" after crash? may help.

Comment: check if maybeSendRegistration is not nil

Comment: Are you seeing symbolicated code? Check your .dSym file of the binary you uploaded.